# Unity how to run awake before static methods are called?

Tags: unity-game-engine, static

I am using a class MyUILayoutManager to manage the sizes of UI elements relative to eachother.
It was my understanding that Awake runs before anything else runs. This seems to be incorrect.

In the Awake() method of the MyUILayoutManager I grab the root canvas and take its measurements:

```
            RectTransform canvasTransform = //get the RectTransform of the canvas
            screenWidth = canvasTransform.sizeDelta.x;
            screenHeight = canvasTransform.sizeDelta.y;
```

Then I have several static methods that size components relative to the canvas size:

```
public static void setSizeRelativeToScreen(
   GameObject gameObject,
   float percentageOfScreenWidth,
   float percentageOfScreenHeight)
```

However, the static methods run before the Awake method determines the size of the canvas. This means the components are sized relative to 0 x 0. Spoiler alert! Multiplying 0 by any value results in 0  so this is not giving the desired results.

Is there a way to make the Awake() run before any static calls are made?

If I try to make Awake() static it cannot access the GameObject that is used to retrieve the canvas's RectTransform.

(I'm using Unity 2019.4.18f1)

Answer (score 0):

unlike Awake(), static methods are not called automatically by Unity, which means that somewhere in your code you're calling that setSizeRelativeToScreen() yourself. You are probably calling it inside Awake() method of another class. The problem with that is that there is no guarantee that the Awake() method using that setSizeRelativeToScreen() will be called after the Awake() method of your MyUILayoutManager class. In order to solve that issue, simply call your setSizeRelativeToScreen() method from inside Start() instead of Awake(), since Start() is called after Awake() and that will fix your issue